How to draw a 6 inch width gdi+ rectangle that is 6 inches regardless of monitor resolution or size;
I have at the start done:
if (SetProcessDpiAwareness(PROCESS_PER_MONITOR_DPI_AWARE) != S_OK) OutputDebugStringA("WARNING: could not set DPI awareness");
if (!SetProcessDpiAwarenessContext(DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_PER_MONITOR_AWARE_V2)) OutputDebugStringA("WARNING: could not set DPI context awareness");

and I have a Gdiplus::Graphics object that I use to draw a rectangle:
Pen colP(Color(255, 255, 255));

auto dpi = GetDpiForWindow(hwnd);

auto newDpi = (2.f * dpi - USER_DEFAULT_SCREEN_DPI);   // messy kludge, it kinda works (don't know why)
gr.DrawRectangle(&colP, 0, 0, lround(newDpi * 6), 30);

This works consistently on two different monitors of different size and resolution.  However, it is a smidge over 6 inches on both screens.  i.e. around 6.1 inches.  The value returned from GetDpiForWindow(hwnd) on one monitor is 120 and the other 144. After applying the messy kludge to the dpi, it becomes 144 and 192 respectively.  Now it's great that the physical length is identical on both monitors but on both it is slightly bigger than 6 inches.  I can fix this by subtracting 2 as in:
auto newDpi = (2.f * dpi - USER_DEFAULT_SCREEN_DPI - 2);

...which makes newDpi 142 and 190 per inch and gives a perfect 6 inches on both monitors
Clearly I have no idea what I'm doing and I'm certain there must be a proper way of doing this that makes sense.  The above works but I need to know either why it works, or better, what's the sensible way of making it work.

No one will guarantee that monitor pixel density is reported correctly.
